# Breaking out of a recursive function?

Tags: python, recursion

I'm wondering how to break out of a recursive loop to the main function. I am trying to do a simple palindrome exercise. The function should return True for `"redivider"` but the `return True` is being passed to `is_pal()` and the function isn't breaking. Short of adding a second variable to `is_pal` to track True/False, what is the proper way to break out of this recursive loop?

```
def first(word):
    return word[0]

def last(word):
    return word[-1]

def middle(word):
    return word[1:-1]

def is_pal(str):    
    if len(str) == 1: 
        return True

    if first(str) == last(str) and len(str) > 1: 
        is_pal(middle(str))
        
print is_pal("redivider")
```

Comment: "The function isn't breaking" is **not an accurate understanding** of the problem in the code shown. There isn't any loop in the first place (recursion doesn't create a loop), so there's nothing to "break" from. But the problem is that simply *calling* recursively has **no effect on** what will be `return`ed "this time", **exactly the same way that** calling **any other** function would not automatically affect what is `return`ed. Please see the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
def is_pal(string):    
    if len(string) <= 1: 
        return True

    if first(string) == last(string): 
        return is_pal(middle(string))
    else:
        return False
```

That way, if they don't match, `False` is returned; if it makes it all the way to the end, True is returned. I also eliminated a redundant conditional and checked for the edge-case of an even-length palindrome.

Comment: Yes but in some cases, recursive has multiple solutions and you may want to stop immediately after the first occurrence instead of progressing any further.

Answer (score 24):

One way to break out of a recursive function in Python is to throw an exception and catch that at the top level. Some people will say that this is not the right way to think about recursion, but it gets the job done. Furthermore, if the task is to identify "problem" elements in an array/array of arrays/ndarray etc., a break technique is convenient, because it stops the algorithm from continuing after the global solution has been identified.

```
def solve_problem(lst):
    def solve_rec(l):
        '''has impl. that may throw an exception '''
    try:
        solve_rec(lst)
        return True
    except:
        return False
```

Comment: This is a much more **general**, and in my opinion, more adaptable, method than the accepted answer.

Comment: @GezaKerecsenyi if you don't mind telling me, I would like to know if breaking out of a recursive or backtracking function like this (catching a raised Exception) would be frowned at during a software engineering technical interview. Thank you in anticipation.

Comment: @Alvindera97 Although I'm still of the opinion that the simplicity of this approach makes it by far the _easiest_, I doubt that it'd be accepted in a professional codebase: the main issue is, what would happen if a 'real' exception is thrown by the code, which has to be handled properly? Therefore, I'd highly suggest thinking through how to control the recursion using bubbling return statements for essentially all situations where fail-safety is needed.

Comment: @GezaKerecsenyi You can always throw a specific exception, (call it RecBreakException or similar), and handle all other exceptions like you would otherwise.

Comment: @garde That's true, but in production applications custom error types would usually be handled by a wrapper class, and so in my opinion mixing raw and tracked error types like this might be considered bad practice.

Comment: @GezaKerecsenyi Well, it would be a local/intrinsic Exception type, and therefore not a system-level error type at all. That is beside the point - style and strategy are always debatable. "Bad practice" is indeed what goes against the chosen style. Using exceptions is bad practice sometimes, it all depends.

Answer (score 19):

You don't "break" out of recursive functions. Trying to do so says you're thinking about them the wrong way. Currently your recursive call is ignoring the output, which means that the recursion is pointless; whatever `is_pal(middle(str))` returns has no effect on the return value of your function.

A recursive algorithm solves the input problem by decomposing the problem into a smaller problem, getting the solution to the smaller problem recursively, and then using the smaller solution to construct a correct solution to the larger problem. You don't "break" out of the inner calls, you return a solution back up one level. You don't know (or need to know) whether you're in an inner call or a top level call. In either case, your function should do the same thing: return `True` if the argument is a palindrome, and `False` if it isn't.

The algorithm you're trying to implement is basically this:

1. If the string is of length 1, it's a palindrome (return `True`)
2. Otherwise, if the first character is the same as the last character, then the input is a palindrome if the middle characters are a palindrome.

So what this means is that once you've established the first and last characters are the same, the answer to "is my input a palindrome" is **exactly the same** as the answer to "are the middle characters a palindrome". You need to return that answer to fulfil your contract. So the recursive call should be `return is_pal(middle(str))` rather than just `is_pal(middle(str))`. If this was a top level call, then that's the answer; if this *wasn't* a top-level call, then the outer call is going to need this answer to work out the answer to the outer problem (in this case, by simply returning it).

---

Btw, your algorithm also has some other problems.

1. You never return `False`, so the answer can never be `False` (in this case you happen to accidentally return `None` by falling off the end of the function if the first and last character don't match, and `None` will probably do as a stand in for `False` in most cases, but it's still not really *correct*).
2. If the string's length is **zero** rather than 1 (which will happen if an empty string is passed in **or** if a palindrome of even length is passed in once all the pairs of equal first and last characters are stripped off), then you don't return the correct answer, and in fact you try to get the first and last character of the empty string, which will cause an exception.

Answer (score 2):

You can exit the program after printing the results using the `exit()` function.

That may not be a good practice, but it might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a return.  Also, don't use `str` as a variable name.  Last thing, the first and last functions could be named slightly better.

```
def first_letter(word):
    return word[0]

def last_letter(word):
    return word[-1]

def middle(word):
    return word[1:-1]

def is_pal(word):    
    if len(word) == 1: 
        return True

    if first_letter(word) == last_letter(word) and len(word) > 1:
        return is_pal(middle(word))

print is_pal("redivider")
```

Comment: This is lacking a `return False` in case `len(word) > 1` and `first_letter(word) != last_letter(word)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return False in case they don't match and add a return statement. Also you will probably want to check against len(str)==0 and len(str)==1:

```
def is_pal(str):
    if len(str) in [0, 1]:
        return True
    if first(str) == last(str) and len(str) > 1:
        return is_pal(middle(str))
    else :
        return False
```

Answer (score -2):

YOU CAN BREAK RECURSION BY RETURNING 1 in 'if' statement before you write your 'function()' 2nd time.
I mean that's what we do to find factorial !! RIGHT?  :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).