# Breaking out of multiple functions at the same time

Tags: python-3.x

I used the search function but could not find a clear answer to my question. This came up but does not really answer it: [Breaking out of a recursive function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544513/breaking-out-of-a-recursive-function)

I am simply trying to create a sort of exit button, this is how the general layout of my program goes, I'll spare the details.

```
def function_1():
while True:
    print('Things...')
    input1 = input('type a, b or c')
    if input = 'a':
        function_2()

def function_2():
while True:
    print('More fun things...')
    input2 = input('type 1, 2, "x" to return to previous menu or "exit" to exit')
    if input2 = 'exit':
        ?????
```

It feels like such a simple question but I'm not sure what to do, tried a few things with no success.
To clarify, 'exit' should quit both functions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`function_2` should `return` a value, and `function_1` should capture that returned value and behave accordingly.  For example:

```
def function_1():
    while True:
        print('Things...')
        input1 = input('type a, b or c')
        if input = 'a':
            quit = function_2()
            if quit:
                return

def function_2():
    while True:
        print('More fun things...')
        input2 = input('type 1, 2, "x" to return to previous menu or "exit" to exit')
        if input2 = 'exit':
            return True
```

Comment: A similar solution would be to create a custom exception and run function_2 inside a try statement. That might make it more readable if one needs to nest more functions than two and still be able to break at several different points.